How can I fetch data with spring data jpa of OneToMany Attribute with FetchType Lazy configuration
can anyone please help with this problem? I have an entity called Staff and with attribute adminStaffResponses which will create a separate table for the OneToMany mapping. I intentionally configure the FetchType to be Lazy, how can I fetch list of StaffRequests by id of staff and with pagination.
This is Staff class
package com.oouweb.staffrequestapp.model.entity;

import com.oouweb.staffrequestapp.model.constant.StaffType;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "staffs")
public class Staff {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String staffId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String middleName;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StaffType staffType;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String profilePicturePathId;

    @Column(name = "is_valid")
    private boolean isValid;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Department department;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private NonAcademicUnit nonAcademicUnit;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<StaffRequest> staffRequests = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "admin_staff_responses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")
    )
    private List<StaffRequest> adminStaffResponses = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "staff_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staffId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )

type here

    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Staff staff = (Staff) o;
        return id == staff.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }
}

This
package com.oouweb.staffrequestapp.model.entity;

import com.oouweb.staffrequestapp.model.constant.RequestResponseStatus;
import com.oouweb.staffrequestapp.model.constant.RequestStatus;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "staff_requests")
public class StaffRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String requestId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String requestSubject;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String reasonForRequest;

    private String attachmentUrl;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RequestStatus requestStatus;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RequestResponseStatus responseStatus;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "admin_request_reviews  ")
    List<RequestReview> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date requestDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Staff staff;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        StaffRequest that = (StaffRequest) o;
        return id == that.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }
}
`

I tried to use native query not but it was bringing ambiguous attribute

`@Query(value = """
            SELECT id, request_id, request_subject, reason_for_request, attachment_url, request_status,                        response_status, request_date
            FROM[tag:tag-name]
            admin_staff_responses asr
            JOIN
            staff_requests sr
            ON
            asr.request_id = sr.id
            WHERE
            asr.staff_id = :staffId
          """, nativeQuery = true)
    List<StaffRequest> findByStaff(int staffId);`


as per implementation, lazy defined relation are loaded automatically when the program code makes use of them. In the meanwhile they are proxied. See this description: https://backendhance.com/en/blog/2023/jpa-fetching-strategies/#lazy-loading
To make use of pagination you should maybe read into https://thorben-janssen.com/pagination-jpa-hibernate/
Pagination is customizable to a certain extend.

You can solve this in several ways. Here's a complete solution:

First, create a repository with a proper JPQL query to avoid the ambiguous column issue:

@Repository
public interface StaffRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<StaffRequest, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT sr FROM StaffRequest sr " +
           "JOIN admin_staff_responses asr ON sr.id = asr.request_id " +
           "WHERE asr.staff_id = :staffId")
    Page<StaffRequest> findStaffRequestsByStaffId(
        @Param("staffId") int staffId, 
        Pageable pageable
    );
}


Create a service to handle the business logic:

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class StaffRequestService {
    private final StaffRequestRepository staffRequestRepository;

    public StaffRequestService(StaffRequestRepository staffRequestRepository) {
        this.staffRequestRepository = staffRequestRepository;
    }

    public Page<StaffRequest> getStaffRequests(
            int staffId, 
            int page, 
            int size, 
            String sortBy
    ) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(
            page, 
            size, 
            Sort.by(sortBy).descending()
        );
        
        return staffRequestRepository.findStaffRequestsByStaffId(staffId, pageable);
    }
}


Controller implementation:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/staff-requests")
public class StaffRequestController {
    private final StaffRequestService staffRequestService;

    public StaffRequestController(StaffRequestService staffRequestService) {
        this.staffRequestService = staffRequestService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/staff/{staffId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<StaffRequest>> getStaffRequests(
            @PathVariable int staffId,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "requestDate") String sortBy
    ) {
        Page<StaffRequest> requests = staffRequestService.getStaffRequests(
            staffId, 
            page, 
            size, 
            sortBy
        );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(requests);
    }
}


For better performance, add appropriate indexes in your database:

@Entity
@Table(name = "admin_staff_responses",
    indexes = {
        @Index(name = "idx_staff_request", columnList = "staff_id,request_id")
    }
)


Optional: Configure batch fetching in application.properties:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size=100

The key points of this solution:

Uses JPQL instead of native query to avoid ambiguous column issues
Properly handles pagination with Spring Data
Maintains the lazy loading configuration
Includes performance optimizations with indexes
Supports sorting and pagination parameters

Usage example:
GET /api/staff-requests/staff/1?page=0&size=10&sortBy=requestDate

Alternative: If you prefer using a native query, you can modify the repository method like this:
@Query(value = """
        SELECT DISTINCT sr.* FROM staff_requests sr
        INNER JOIN admin_staff_responses asr ON asr.request_id = sr.id
        WHERE asr.staff_id = :staffId
        """, 
      countQuery = """
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sr.id) FROM staff_requests sr
        INNER JOIN admin_staff_responses asr ON asr.request_id = sr.id
        WHERE asr.staff_id = :staffId
        """,
      nativeQuery = true)
Page<StaffRequest> findStaffRequestsByStaffIdNative(
    @Param("staffId") int staffId, 
    Pageable pageable
);

This solution avoids the N+1 query problem while maintaining proper pagination and lazy loading configuration.

The second approach worked with native query but the first one is throwing ```Caused by: org.hibernate.query.PathException: Could not resolve join path 'admin_staff_responses'
at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.QualifiedJoinPathConsumer$ExpectingEntityJoinDelegate.consumeIdentifier(QualifiedJoinPathConsumer.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]


I will really appreciate if you can help me solve that because I love to use JPQL a lot.

Your issue seems to be about a query with nothing to do with lazy/eager fetching. Note that what you've implemented is a unidirectional one to many and it might be easier if you put an entity over the admin_staff_responses table.
Using what you have, the JPQL will be simply:
"Select sr FROM Staff s join s.adminStaffResponses sr where s.id = :staffId"
This will generate SQL that won't match your native SQL - it has to do an extra join under the covers. Using an intermediary class can allow you to access the  admin_staff_responses table directly in JPQL if you wish to avoid the extra join the JPQL requires from Staff->admin_staff_responses, but might not affect performance enough to be worth changing and complicating your model.
